# How to fetch data and update an Alpine object after a custom JavaScript event?

Tags: javascript, events, django-templates, alpine.js

I am trying to trigger a custom JavascriptEvent to signal that certain action (a modal is closed) has been done, after which I am trying to fetch data from an API and update an Alpine object. Here's my modal-related code:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
        Alpine.data('settings', () => ({

        ...other stuff here...

        postSettings() {
            if (this.settings.userEdited) {
                fetch('/settings', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRFToken': document.head.querySelector('meta[name=csrf-token]').content
                },
                body: new FormData(settingsForm)
                })
                .then(response => response.text())
                .then(text => this.settingsId = text)
                .finally(() => this.$dispatch('settingsUpdated'))
            }  
            },
            
        }))
    })
</script>

<section style="width: 100%;" x-data="settings" @keydown.escape="settingsModalOpen = false; postSettings();">

...Rest of the HTML related to the modal...
```

I'm developing a Django web app, and the modal is included to other templates. In another specific template, in which the modal is included I have a script which is listening for event 'settingsUpdated':

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
        Alpine.data('results', () => ({

            results: [],

            init() {
                this.getResultsValues()
                window.addEventListener('settingsUpdated', this.getResultsValues)
            },

            getResultsValues() {
            fetch("/api/results")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => this.results = json)
            },

        }))
    })
</script>
```

The issue I'm facing is that the `this.results` does not get updated if the event is triggered. I can see from the browser developer tools tab that the event is clearly 'catched' and a GET request is sent to `/settings` but for some reason the Alpine object `this.results` is not updated after the data is fetched. The same data is succesfully fetched and mounted to the object when the page is initialized ( `init() {this.getResultsValues()...}`) but for some reason the same function does not update the results object in case the function is triggered by an event (`window.addEventListener('settingsUpdated', this.getResultsValues)`).

Comment: And you're certain the event is dispatched and arrives in the event listener?

Comment: @Yinci Yes. If I for example replace the `.then(json => this.results = json)` in the getResultsValues function with `.then(() => console.log('something'))` the text is logged into the console after I've closed the modal.

Comment: have you tried making it async ? `('settingsUpdated', async this.getResultsValues)` and `async getResultsValues() {` and `await fetch("/api/results").then(await response => response.json())`